# mootools toggle divs with css effect on button

Tags: javascript, toggle, mootools

I have the below script to show/hide some text. I want to make the toggle button an image that change when clicked on. (e.g. "+ Title 1" when collapse and "- Title 1" when expanded) Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
window.addEvent( 'domready', function(){
$$( '.moreInfoWrapper' ).each(function(item){
    var thisSlider = new Fx.Slide( item.getElement( '.moreInfo' ), { duration: 500 } );
    thisSlider.hide();
    item.getElement( '.divToggle' ).addEvent( 'click', function(){ thisSlider.toggle(); } );
} );
} );
```

Html:

```
<div class='moreInfoWrapper'>
    <div class='divToggle'>
        <h3>Title 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class='moreInfo'>
        <h3>More Info About Item 1</h3>
        <p>Here is some content.</p>
        <p>More Content</p>
        <p>End of Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='moreInfoWrapper'>
    <div class='divToggle'>
        <h3>Title 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class='moreInfo'>
        <h3>More Info About Item 2</h3>
        <p>Here is some content.</p>
        <p>More Content</p>
        <p>End of Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be so textually (or could be changed CSS class). It's a bit clumsy solution, but it works. Maybe someone responds better.

```
$$('.moreInfoWrapper .moreInfo').each(function(item){
    item.set('slide', { duration: 500 }).slide('hide');
});

$$('.moreInfoWrapper .divToggle').each(function(item){
  item.addEvent('click', function(e){
    var el = this.getFirst('h3');
    if (this.getNext('div').getDimensions().height == 0) {
      el.set('html', el.get('html').replace('+','-'));
    } else {
      el.set('html', el.get('html').replace('-','+'));
    }
    this.getNext('div').getFirst('.moreInfo').slide('toggle');
  });
});
```

Ty it [on this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fjuf63x7/).